# Transform string to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have the following JavaScript object, how could I serialize it to a string in the JSON data exchange format?

```
var result = { "id": "358464" ,"t" : "MSFT" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "28.03" ,"l_cur" : "28.04" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT" ,"lt" : "Mar 15, 4:00PM EDT" ,"c" : "-0.10" ,"cp" : "-0.36" ,"ccol" : "chr" }
```

I tried `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` and both did not work for me

The problem is that:

For example, `result.l` returns undefined.

What possible causes might this have? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it [JSON](http://json.org/) already?

Comment: If it's actually a string (a JSON text) then it **is** JSON. If it's an object, as the snippet in the question implies, then `JSON.stringify` will work.

Comment: This is a trick question, it already is JSON.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: curiously enough, the question states "but this does work.", sounds like our work here is done... =P

Comment: Did you forget your `;`?

Comment: You might find what you're looking for here: http://freshbrewedcode.com/jimcowart/2013/01/29/what-you-might-not-know-about-json-stringify/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it really works:

```
var str = '{ "id": "358464" ,"t" : "MSFT" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "28.03" ,"l_cur" : "28.04" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT" ,"lt" : "Mar 15, 4:00PM EDT" ,"c" : "-0.10" ,"cp" : "-0.36" ,"ccol" : "chr" }';
var jsObj = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(jsObj);
var jsonStrAgain = JSON.stringify(jsObj);
console.log(jsonStrAgain);
```

And this works as well (having nothing to do with JSON, just being an object literal):

```
var result = { "id": "358464" ,"t" : "MSFT" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "28.03" ,"l_cur" : "28.04" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"4:00PM EDT" ,"lt" : "Mar 15, 4:00PM EDT" ,"c" : "-0.10" ,"cp" : "-0.36" ,"ccol" : "chr" };
console.log(result.l); // "28.03"
```